# How to send a hashmap within a POST or GET query in Java tomcat server?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I have a bunch of key value pairs that I would like the client to send to my REST API. In the POST query, I presume I can take a hashmap, convert it to a JSON string and send it as a single query param input? I then decode this back into JSON on the server side. Would that work? How about for the GET query though? Would the user have to write JSON in the http string?

Comment: *"decode this back into JSON on the server side"*?? It's already JSON, so did you perhaps mean to decode the JSON back into a `Map`?

Comment: If the Map keys and values are both `String`, you can send the name/value pairs in a GET as query parameters. Similarly, you can send the name/value pairs in a POST using content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You can also send in a POST using `application/json` like you suggested. Don't send JSON in a GET (you can, but it's not recommended), and be aware that GET requests have a size limit.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. Yeah, after a bit of thinking, you are right, once I am sending more complex data structures over to the server, its better to use a proper client and use a POST request vs. a GET request.